# Specify gridlines style to `extra y tick labels`

Tags: pgfplots, grids

I couldn't understand how to style additional grid lines added with `extra y tick style`.

Perhaps I am missing something. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306095/180429) it is explained how to draw grid lines only at specified positions, and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51870/180429) actually explains it, but nothing is rendered in my current code.

The MWE is the following:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
t,ch1,ch2,ch3
-4,-2,0.0625,0.756
-3,-1.5,0.125,-0.141
-2,-1,0.25,-0.909
-1,-0.5,0.5,-0.841
0,0,1,0
1,0.5,2,0.841
2,1,4,0.909
3,1.5,8,0.141
4,2,16,-0.758
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  ymin=-4,
  ymax=17
  }
%% ch2 plot
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel={Time [\si{s}]},
    ylabel={Current [\si{\A}]},
    grid=major
]
\addplot [green] table[x=t,y=ch2,col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}

%% ch3 plot
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xtick=\empty,
    ylabel={Voltage (Normalised)},
    ylabel style={red},
extra y ticks={-1,1},   %% <-- Here starts the confusion
        extra y tick labels={-3,5},
        extra y tick style={
            grid=major,
        },
]
\addplot [red] table[x=t,y=ch3,col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So I succeeded drawing grid lines at `y=-1` and `y=+1`, with labels `-3` and `5` respectively, but now I want to style it in red, with line width=2pt, and "densely dashed".

How to do it?

I tried also this:

```
extra y tick style={y tick label style={draw=red}}
```

But the output is now a red frame around the extra labels.

And this

```
extra y tick style={y tick label style={line width=2pt}}
```

doesn't plot any extra grid lines.

Any help?

Comment: Have a look here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122751/change-color-of-extra-ticks-grid), this should help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122751/change-color-of-extra-ticks-grid) deals with your topic.

You can specify the style of the mayor grid lines of the extra ticks using `major grid style={...}` in the `extra y tick style` environment.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    t,ch1,ch2,ch3
    -4,-2,0.0625,0.756
    -3,-1.5,0.125,-0.141
    -2,-1,0.25,-0.909
    -1,-0.5,0.5,-0.841
    0,0,1,0
    1,0.5,2,0.841
    2,1,4,0.909
    3,1.5,8,0.141
    4,2,16,-0.758
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
            ymin=-4,
            ymax=17
        }
        %% ch2 plot
        \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            axis y line*=left,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            xlabel={Time [\si{s}]},
            ylabel={Current [\si{\A}]},
            grid=major
            ]
            \addplot [green] table[x=t,y=ch2,col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
        
        %% ch3 plot
        \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            xtick=\empty,
            ylabel={Voltage (Normalised)},
            ylabel style={red},
            extra y ticks={-1,1},   %% <-- Here starts the confusion
            extra y tick labels={-3,5},
            extra y tick style={
                grid=major,
                major grid style={red, line width=2pt, densely dashed}, % <- this solves your problem
            },
            ]
            \addplot [red] table[x=t,y=ch3,col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```